# $n$th derivative is also constant of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

Prove that if the Hamiltonian and a quantity $F$ are constants of motion then the $n$th partial derivative of $F$ w.r.t. time $t$ must also be a constant of motion.